# how to use hive table as a input in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, hadoop, hive

I have 3 tables in Hive.  I want to use these 3 tables as a input in python and update some column values per some conditions.  After updating the column values, put them into a new hive table.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: This is extremely broad and impossible to answer as is.  Please update the question with example data, your Hive and Python code, and what your desired output is.  The more information you provide, the higher probability of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a coincidence, i just write a python script one hour age for the first time.

use TRANSFORM : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform

```
add file hive_recursion.py;

select transform(id, category_parent_id, '===') using 'python hive_recursion.py' as ( xxx ) 
from navigation_category limit 111;
```

Comment: Thanks . its fixed... Thanks a lot